# How to play mp3 files using Brightcove player in android?

Tags: android, brightcove

Is there any way to play mp3 files on brightcove player. Using brightcove sdk to play video files. Now I want to play mp3 file.

Comment: Provide what you've tried and errors or the unexpected you're getting

Comment: No..i didn't.. i just want to know is that possible or not?